# How to make my two text elements "stick" more together

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to recreate this part of a website using HTML&CSS : [image: 1]
and my part looks like this : [image]
The size difference of the elements doesn't matter here but what triggers me is that in the first image, you can see the heading and the paragraph are "sticking" together. In my version, there is a space between them, and I can't figure out how to remove it.

Here are the concerned code lines :

```css
.cta {
  background: #3882f6;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  color: #f9faf8;
}

.cta-container {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.cta-signup-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.cta-signup {
  background: #3882f6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: none;
  color: #f9faf8;
  width: 120px;
  height: 33px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid #f9faf8;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta-container">
  <div class="cta">
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
      <h3>Call to action! It's time!</h3>
      <div class="cta-signup-wrapper">
        <p>Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!</p> <button type="button" class="cta-signup">Sign up</button> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried playing around with the paragraph, removing it, or nesting the `cta-signup-wrapper` differently but without success.

Comment: Huge top and button margin on the h3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can try this logic :

```css
.cta {
      background: #3882f6;
      padding: 50px 100px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      border-style: none;
      color: #f9faf8;
    }

    .cta-container {
      padding: 100px 0;
    }

    .cta-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .cta-signup-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: start;
    }

    .cta-signup-wrapper > * {
      margin-top: -1em;
    }

  

.cta-signup {
  background: #3882f6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: none;
  color: #f9faf8;
  width: 120px;
  height: 33px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid #f9faf8;
  margin-top: -1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="cta-container">
      <div class="cta">
        <div class="cta-wrapper">
          <div class="cta-signup-wrapper">
            <h3>Call to action! It's time!</h3>
            <p>
              Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!
            </p>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="cta-signup">Sign up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just now i  Modified my answer

Comment: I only added the line : .cta-signup-wrapper > * { margin-top: -1em; } and it worked! Why did you add a margin-top: -1em; to the button as well ? Thanks.

Comment: to make it in level as it was shown in your image

Comment: equal minus from both element , if you don't need then you can ignore margin-top: -1em; to the button

Answer (score -1):

`h3` and `p` elements have a lot of margin by default (`h3` margin highlighted in orange below):

[image]

Fix that by removing your `h3`'s `margin-bottom` and `p`'s `margin-top`:

```css
.cta {
  background: #3882f6;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  color: #f9faf8;
}

.cta-container {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.cta-signup-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.cta-signup {
  background: #3882f6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: none;
  color: #f9faf8;
  width: 120px;
  height: 33px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid #f9faf8;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta-container">
  <div class="cta">
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
      <h3>Call to action! It's time!</h3>
      <div class="cta-signup-wrapper">
        <p>Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!</p>
        <button type="button" class="cta-signup">Sign up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Huge dupe already answered in the comment. Please do not answer such simple questions - they can be commented and deleted

Comment: Strangely your solution didn't work.. but adding this made it work : .cta-signup-wrapper > * { margin-top: -1em; } . I already have an universal selector on my css removing margin, padding and setting it to border-box. Maybe that's why?